# Отмена НЕ всех действий по умолчанию preventDefault()

Tags: javascript

Есть простая форма

```js
var inp = document.forms[0].send;
inp.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('click');
});
```

```html
<form action="/">
  <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Заполни меня" required>
  <input type="submit" name="send" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Проблема в том, что когда я вызываю
e.preventDefault() - браузер отменяет действие проверки на содержимое тега, у которого установлен required. И даже если он пустой - он пропускает.

Вот вопрос такой, реально ли как то не отменять это действие? Или только  функцию на проверку содержимого писать?

Comment: проверка осуществляется перед отправкой. так как до отправки (submit) дело не дошло, так как отключили дефолтное поведение на клике. то и проверки соответственно нет

Comment: точно, на submit работает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проверка осуществляется перед отправкой. так как до отправки (submit) дело не дошло, так как отключили дефолтное поведение на клике. то и проверки соответственно нет.

Если перенести `e.preventDefault();` в обработчик *submit* формы, то проверка сработает.

```js
var inp = document.forms[0].addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('submit');
});
```

```html
<form action="/">
  <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Заполни меня" required>
  <input type="submit" name="send" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Comment: Чем отличается `addEventListener` от `onsubmit = function`?

Comment: @Doofy, [_addEventListener_](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) позволяет несколько обработчиков добавить